# Align poem title with verses

Tags: verse, poetry

How do I align poem title in the `verse` environment with the poem's text?

```
\poemtitle{Raven}
\begin{verse}[\linewidth]
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,\\*
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—\\*
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,\\*
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.\\*
“’Tis some visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door—\\*
Only this and nothing more.”
```

gives me:

[image]

I would like the Raven title be aligned to the left with the poem's verses, on both left and right pages.

Comment: I'd say `\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\raggedright}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately managed to make it work, thanks to @egreg's suggestion:

```
\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\raggedright\normalfont\large\bfseries\hspace{\leftmargin}}
```